# I am very stuck in how to add takeaway option as define isn't working

Tags: python, tkinter

In my code I have got it to work by adding up the amount of drinks I want to buy however when trying to add code so that if they type yes into the takeaway entry box it will add 5% on to the total. 
I have added it within a def using an if statement however it doesn't seem to be registering that that define exists. I added a print('hi') after it and even that doesn't show up. I'm quite new to python and after looking quite a lot i don't know what to do. Also i know that my code is probably really badly organised and messy but I don't know how to fix this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my entire code its not too long the main problem is the def Takeaway() does not register when running the program.

```
from tkinter import*
import random
import time
import datetime

root=Tk()
root.geometry("1600x8000")
root.title("Cafe au Lait")

Tops=Frame(root, width=1600,relief=SUNKEN)
Tops.pack(side=TOP)

f1=Frame(root,width=800,height=700,relief=SUNKEN)
f1.pack(side=LEFT)


localtime=time.asctime(time.localtime(time.time()))

lblInfo=Label(Tops,font=('helvetica',50,'bold'),text="Cafe au Lait ",fg="Black",bd=10,anchor='w')
lblInfo.grid(row=0,column=0)

lblInfo=Label(Tops,font=('arial',20,'bold'),text=localtime,fg="Steel Blue",bd=10,anchor='w')
lblInfo.grid(row=1,column=0)

def Ref():
    x=random.randint(10908,500876)
    randomRef=str(x)
    rand.set(randomRef)

if (Latte.get()==""):
    CoL=0
else:
    CoL=float(Latte.get())



if (Iced.get()==""):
    CoI=0
else:
    CoI=float(Iced.get())



if (FlatWhite.get()==""):
    CoFW=0
else:
    CoFW=float(FlatWhite.get())



if (DoubleExpresso.get()==""):
    CoDE=0
else:
    CoDE=float(DoubleExpresso.get())


if (Cappacuino.get()==""):
    CoC=0
else:
    CoC=float(Cappacuino.get())


if (Expresso.get()==""):
    CoE=0
else:
    CoE=float(Expresso.get())


CostofLatte =CoL * 3.5
CostofIced =CoI * 2.5
CostofFlatWhite =CoFW* 3.75
CostofDoubleExpresso =CoDE * 4.25
CostofCappacuino =CoC* 3.75
CostofExpresso =CoE * 3

CostofMeal= "$", str('%.2f' % (CostofLatte+CostofIced+CostofFlatWhite+CostofDoubleExpresso+CostofCappacuino+CostofExpresso))

TotalCost=(CostofLatte+CostofIced+CostofFlatWhite+CostofDoubleExpresso+CostofCappacuino+CostofExpresso)

OverAllCost ="$", str ('%.2f' % TotalCost)#(PayTax+TotalCost+Ser_Charge))

Cost.set(CostofMeal)

Total.set(OverAllCost)


def Takeaway():
    if (Takeaway == 'Yes') or (Takeaway == 'yes') or (Takeaway == 'y') or 
(Takeaway == 'Y'):
    OverAllCost = (OverAllCost/20 + OverAllCost)
    print(OverAllCost)
elif (Takeaway == 'No', 'no', 'n', 'N'):
    OverAllCost = (OverAllCost)

def Takeaway():
    if Takeaway == 'Yes':
        print ('hi')

def qExit():
    root.destroy()

def Reset():
    rand.set("") 
    Latte.set("")
    FlatWhite.set("")
    DoubleExpresso.set("")
    Total.set("")

    Iced.set("")

    Cost.set("")
    Cappacuino.set("")
    Expresso.set("")
    Takeaway.set("")


rand = StringVar()
Latte=StringVar()
DoubleExpresso=StringVar()

Total=StringVar()

Iced=StringVar()

Cost=StringVar()
Cappacuino=StringVar()
Expresso=StringVar()
FlatWhite=StringVar()


lblTakeaway= Label(f1, font=('arial', 16, 'bold'),text="Takeaway",bd=16,anchor="w")
lblTakeaway.grid(row=6, column=0)
txtTakeaway=Entry(f1, font=('arial',16,'bold'),textvariable=Takeaway,bd=10,insertwidth=4,bg="powder blue",justify='right')
txtTakeaway.grid(row=6,column=1)



lblCost= Label(f1, font=('arial', 16, 'bold'),text="Cost of Order",bd=16,anchor="w")
lblCost.grid(row=1, column=2)
txtCost=Entry(f1, font=('arial',16,'bold'),textvariable=Cost,bd=10,insertwidth=4,bg="powder blue",justify='right')
txtCost.grid(row=1,column=3)








lblTotalCost= Label(f1, font=('arial', 16, 'bold'),text="Total Cost",bd=16,anchor="w")
lblTotalCost.grid(row=5, column=2)
txtTotalCost=Entry(f1, font=('arial',16,'bold'),textvariable=Total,bd=10,insertwidth=4,bg="powder blue",justify='right')
txtTotalCost.grid(row=5,column=3)





root.mainloop()
```

I had some problems putting it into this website so i took away some of the buttons but I have left everything relating to the total and the takeaway i am having problems with. 
If it helps i have not received any error message it just doesn't print at all.

Comment: One problem is you have 2 functions called Takeaway and one variable. This is most likely the issue and you should never name multiple objects the same thing.

Comment: the 2 functions called takeaway are just to show the 2 things ive tried. when i do it alone on either it doesnt work.

Comment: You have several problems in your code. You do not define your `textvariable` of `Takeaway` your indention in your example is broken so your code cant even run as is. You never call your `Takeaway` function anywhere in your code. Your placement of your variables is not going to work. This needs a complete rewrite.

Comment: Do you know any websites or anything to help me re write it or how it should be formatted?

Comment: I am working on a version right now. It will take me a bit of time but I will post when ready.

Comment: Thanks very much ill try do some stuff to fix it myself now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has a few problems. I think you are not understanding how Tkinter works. Tkinter is event driven and all your if statements in the global only run at the start of the program and not with the mainloop over and over. What you need to do here is move everything you need into the `ref()` function and manage your calculations there.

Most of your variables should be `IntVar()` instead of `StringVar`.

A lot of your assignments were redundant so I simplified some of your code. That said your code could be simplified further but I left some of that for you to ponder over.

Not everything needs a variable name. All of your Label's can do without being assigned to a variable here.

Your `Takeaway` function is not needed. We can just check at the end of `ref` if yes on the entry field and then do some extra math for the total.

The simplest way to get your total is to bind `Return` to `root` and call `ref`.

I also reworked your code to better fit the PEP8 guidelines for writing code.
Things like variable_names with all lower case and underscores. [You can read more on PEP8 here.](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Take a look at the below code and let me know if you have any questions.

Updated my example to include one of the drinks.
Based on you GitHub link in the comments here is the fixed version.

```
import tkinter as tk
import time

root = tk.Tk()
#root.geometry("1600x8000")
root.title("Cafe au Lait")

tops = tk.Frame(root, width=1600, relief="sunken")
tops.pack(side="top")
f1 = tk.Frame(root, width=800, height=700, relief="sunken")
f1.pack(side="left")

localtime = time.asctime(time.localtime(time.time()))

tk.Label(tops, font=('helvetica',50,'bold'), text="Cafe au Lait ", fg="Black", bd=10, anchor='w').grid(row=0, column=0)
tk.Label(tops, font=('arial',20,'bold'), text=localtime, fg="Steel Blue", bd=10, anchor='w').grid(row=1, column=0)

latte = tk.DoubleVar()
double_expresso = tk.DoubleVar()
iced = tk.DoubleVar()
cost = tk.DoubleVar()
cappacuino = tk.DoubleVar()
expresso = tk.DoubleVar()
flat_white = tk.DoubleVar()
total = tk.DoubleVar()
takeaway_var = tk.StringVar()

def ref(even=None):
    global total, cost
    if latte.get() == "":
        col = 0
    else:
        col = latte.get() 
    if iced.get() == "":
        coi = 0
    else:
        coi = iced.get()
    if flat_white.get() == "":
        cofw = 0
    else:
        cofw = flat_white.get()
    if double_expresso.get() == "":
        code = 0
    else:
        code = double_expresso.get()
    if cappacuino.get() == "":
        coc = 0
    else:
        coc = cappacuino.get()
    if expresso.get() == "":
        coe = 0
    else:
        coe = expresso.get()

    costoflatte = col * 3.5
    costoficed = coi * 2.5
    costofflat_white = cofw * 3.75
    costofdouble_expresso = code * 4.25
    costofcappacuino = coc * 3.75
    costofexpresso = coe * 3

    total.set('{}'.format(cost.get() + costoflatte + costoficed + costofflat_white + costofdouble_expresso + costofcappacuino + costofexpresso))
    print('{}'.format(cost.get() + costoflatte + costoficed + costofflat_white + costofdouble_expresso + costofcappacuino + costofexpresso))
    if txt_takeaway.get() in ['Yes', 'yes', 'y', 'Y']:
        x = total.get()
        y = x * 0.05
        print(x, y)
        total.set(y + x)

def q_exit():
    root.destroy()

def reset():
    global latte, flat_white, double_expresso, total, iced, cost, cappacuino, expresso, takeaway_var 
    latte = tk.DoubleVar()
    double_expresso = tk.DoubleVar()
    iced = tk.DoubleVar()
    cost = tk.DoubleVar()
    cappacuino = tk.DoubleVar()
    expresso = tk.DoubleVar()
    flat_white = tk.DoubleVar()
    total = tk.DoubleVar()
    takeaway_var = tk.StringVar()

tk.Label(f1, font=('arial', 16, 'bold'), text="Takeaway", bd=16, anchor="w").grid(row=6, column=0)
txt_takeaway = tk.Entry(f1, font=('arial',16,'bold'),textvariable=takeaway_var, bd=10, insertwidth=4, bg="powder blue", justify='right')
txt_takeaway.grid(row=6, column=1)

tk.Label(f1, font=('arial', 16, 'bold'), text="cost of Order", bd=16, anchor="w").grid(row=1, column=2)
txt_cost = tk.Entry(f1, font=('arial',16,'bold'), textvariable=cost,bd=10, insertwidth=4, bg="powder blue", justify='right')
txt_cost.grid(row=1, column=3)

tk.Label(f1, font=('arial', 16, 'bold'), text="total cost", bd=16, anchor="w").grid(row=5, column=2)
txt_totalcost = tk.Entry(f1, font=('arial',16,'bold'), textvariable=total, bd=10, insertwidth=4, bg="powder blue", justify='right')
txt_totalcost.grid(row=5, column=3)

tk.Label(f1, font=('arial', 16, 'bold'),text="Latte",bd=16,anchor="w").grid(row=1, column=0)
txt_latte=tk.Entry(f1, font=('arial',16,'bold'),textvariable=latte,bd=10,insertwidth=4,bg="powder blue",justify='right')
txt_latte.grid(row=1,column=1)


tk.Label(f1, font=('arial', 16, 'bold'),text="Flat White",bd=16,anchor="w").grid(row=2, column=0)
txt_flat_white=tk.Entry(f1, font=('arial',16,'bold'),textvariable=flat_white,bd=10,insertwidth=4,bg="powder blue",justify='right')
txt_flat_white.grid(row=2,column=1)


tk.Label(f1, font=('arial', 16, 'bold'),text="Double Expresso",bd=16,anchor="w").grid(row=3, column=0)
txt_double_expresso=tk.Entry(f1, font=('arial',16,'bold'),textvariable=double_expresso,bd=10,insertwidth=4,bg="powder blue",justify='right')
txt_double_expresso.grid(row=3,column=1)

tk.Label(f1, font=('arial', 16, 'bold'),text="Cappacuino",bd=16,anchor="w").grid(row=4, column=0)
txt_cappacuino=tk.Entry(f1, font=('arial',16,'bold'),textvariable=cappacuino,bd=10,insertwidth=4,bg="powder blue",justify='right')
txt_cappacuino.grid(row=4,column=1)

tk.Label(f1, font=('arial', 16, 'bold'),text="Expresso",bd=16,anchor="w").grid(row=5, column=0)
txt_expresso=tk.Entry(f1, font=('arial',16,'bold'),textvariable=expresso,bd=10,insertwidth=4,bg="powder blue",justify='right')
txt_expresso.grid(row=5,column=1)

tk.Label(f1, font=('arial', 16, 'bold'),text="Iced",bd=16,anchor="w").grid(row=0, column=0)
txt_iced=tk.Entry(f1, font=('arial',16,'bold'),textvariable=iced,bd=10,insertwidth=4,bg="powder blue",justify='right')
txt_iced.grid(row=0,column=1)

btnTotal=tk.Button(f1,padx=16,pady=8,bd=16,fg="black",font=('arial',16,'bold'),width=10,text="Total",bg="powder blue",command=ref).grid(row=7,column=1)


root.bind("<Return>", ref)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: @Jsam that is a separate issue than the one you were having in this question. Please accept the answer and ask a new question. I suspect you are missing something either in your if statements or formula.

Comment: Sorry yeah my bad. It came up with this message when i tried to total it- File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1702, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
TypeError: ref() missing 1 required positional argument: 'event'

Comment: @Jsam That can be fixed. replace `ref(event)` with `ref(event=None)` and it should work as before. I also updated my code to include a drink and a small fix to the math.

Comment: Thank you for this code. It all works except when i add the Yes for the takeaway it makes the total 0 and doesnt add it together. Ill try figure this out myself. Its 10pm my time and i have school tomorrow so i need to go to sleep. bye and thanks very much.

Comment: The yes, Yes, Y and y work on my end. Let me take a look.

Comment: Not sure why you are having issues with the math after putting in yes but it is working on my end.

Comment: My code is the same but I have added event=none rather then just event and i have added a few more labels and entries for other drinks which all work also. I have also added a button which executes the ref

Comment: Hum. If you have a GitHub account you can upload your code and link it to me and I can check it for you.

Comment: I could put it on pastebin it can be set automatically in python so u just c and p

Comment: Sorry I cannot access pastebin from work. It is blocked. Only Github. I can check when I get home tonight thought if you cant get a Github account.

Comment: The fix is to change `x = cost.get()` to `x = total.get()` inside of the `ref()` function in the if statement at the bottom. I have already made that fix in my code I mentioned it in a previous comment.

Comment: Does when you put 1 in iced section and yes in takeaway the value goes down. mine for some reason goes down to 2.1

Comment: Hum. That is interesting. I will take a look at the math and try to find why that is happening.

Comment: I might have missed something but when I looked at it and using a calculator it seemed good.

Comment: Fixed it. Change all the `tk.IntVar()`'s to `tk.DoubleVar()` and it fixes the math. The problem with `IntVar` is that a float will get converted to the nearest whole. Don't forget to change it in the reset function as well.

Comment: Honestly. You are a god on earth. Thanks so much.

Comment: @Jsam lol. Thanks. I just enjoy Python and helping. Make sure to select the checkmark next to my answer if it solved your problem.